# Query to create a table in amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I try to create in amazon athena a new table if not exist and add a resume about how many measures gotten of sensor, but i get a error about the creation of table.

i am using awswrangler

this is the query

```
        query = f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cantidad_mediciones_por_cliente_sensor WITH (
        format = 'Parquet',
        write_compression = 'SNAPPY',
        external_location = 's3://{self.params['bucket']}/{self.params['path']}/',
        partitioned_by = ARRAY['year', 'month', 'day']
        ) AS
        SELECT count  (distinct (fecha_hora)) as "cantidad_mediciones",
            sensor.id_sensor as "id_sensor",
            sensor.descripcion_sensor as "descripcion_sensor",
            sensor.tag_sensor as "tag_sensor",
            tipo_dispositivo.tipo_sensor as "tipo_sensor",
            tipo_dispositivo.id as "id_tipo_sensor",
            cliente.nombre_cliente as "nombre_cliente",
            cliente.id_cliente as "id_cliente",
            partition_0 as "year",
            partition_1 as "month",
            partition_2 as "day"
        FROM "{self.BASE_DE_DATOS}"."{self.TABLA}"
        WHERE (CAST(partition_0 as smallint) = {self.yesterday.year})
            and (CAST(partition_1 as tinyint) = {self.yesterday.month})
            and (CAST (partition_2 as tinyint) = {self.yesterday.day})
        GROUP BY sensor.id_sensor,
            sensor.descripcion_sensor,
            sensor.tag_sensor,
            tipo_dispositivo.tipo_sensor,
            tipo_dispositivo.id,
            cliente.id_cliente,
            cliente.nombre_cliente,
            partition_0,    
            partition_1,
            partition_2"""
```

and i got this error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: line 4:4: mismatched input 'CREATE'. Expecting: '(', <query>",
  "errorType": "InvalidRequestException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/measurement_daily_src/lambda_function.py\", line 80, in lambda_handler\n    query_for_athena.obtener()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/measurement_daily_src/lambda_function.py\", line 22, in obtener\n    df_resumen_diario = self._obtener_datos_desde_athena()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/measurement_daily_src/lambda_function.py\", line 68, in _obtener_datos_desde_athena\n    return wr.athena.read_sql_query(query, self.BASE_DE_DATOS, workgroup=self.params['workgroup'])\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/_config.py\", line 450, in wrapper\n    return function(**args)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/athena/_read.py\", line 854, in read_sql_query\n    return _resolve_query_without_cache(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/athena/_read.py\", line 422, in _resolve_query_without_cache\n    return _resolve_query_without_cache_ctas(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/athena/_read.py\", line 263, in _resolve_query_without_cache_ctas\n    ctas_query_info: Dict[str, Union[str, _QueryMetadata]] = create_ctas_table(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/_config.py\", line 450, in wrapper\n    return function(**args)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/athena/_utils.py\", line 821, in create_ctas_table\n    raise ex\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/athena/_utils.py\", line 800, in create_ctas_table\n    query_execution_id: str = _start_query_execution(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/athena/_utils.py\", line 98, in _start_query_execution\n    response: Dict[str, Any] = _utils.try_it(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/_utils.py\", line 343, in try_it\n    return f(**kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 530, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 960, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you remove parts of the request until the error goes away. For example, remove the WHERE first. Then, remove the GROUP BY section and the COUNT. I got it to work with a very stripped-down version of: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo1 WITH (format = 'Parquet', write_compression = 'SNAPPY', external_location = 's3://bucket/folder/') AS SELECT 'foo' as message`, so it's something in your SELECT that is causing the problem.

Comment: Can't see any syntax issue. Maybe try the CTAS statement in the Athena console query editor and check the error message?